# BOOST C++ установка, проблема

Tags: c++, boost

Здраствуйте.
Скачал boost 1.67.0, распаковал, через коммандную  строку запустил bootstrap.bat, затем b2.bat. Всё утановилось успешно. Теперь когда создаю новый проект С++, подключаю буст указав в настройках проекта:

C/C++->долнительные каталоги включаемых библиотек->папка с буст:
[image: 2]

далее компоновщик->долнительные каталоги библиотек->папка stage/lib:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но с использованием возникаем проблема:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите решить проблему, очень долго не могу разобраться!Спасибо.

Comment: А эти настройки указана для выбранной конфигурации?

Comment: Подробнее пожалуйста, я первый раз пытаюсь установить Boost

Answer (score 0):

Ну boost - немного не php...

> ```
> #include <boost/thread.php>
> ```

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
```

Comment: Да, тут я ошибся)) исправил на .hpp но результат тот же(

Answer (score -1):

Я подключал так:

Каталоги VC++/Включаемые каталоги папку boost_xxx

Каталоги VC++/Каталоги библиотек папку boost_xxx\stage\lib

Есть ещё очень удобный диспетчер пакетов vcpkg. Там не только boost, но много ещё других библиотек. Позволяет очень легко их устанавливать.

[Тут можно почитать как пользоваться.](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/vcpkg)

Comment: Спасибо огромное за vcpkg!